# not getting increment after clicking in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a link when someone click on it he go on first page and second person click on link they will go on second link. but i am not getting increment after clicking. this is my code

```
<?php
$links = array('https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java', 'https://seomagnifier.com/backlinks-maker');
$currentLink = isset($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] : 0;
if ($currentLink >= Count($links)) {
  $currentLink = 0;
}
$link = $links[$currentLink];
$currentLink++;
header("Location: $link?link=$currentLink");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: but it is only same person. how to do for every person...first person click go to first page and second person click go to second page and so on..

Comment: go for saving these click in database (best suitable option) or use super global variables